# correct count of grouped results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetActualFeedbackQueueTree]
    @dtNow datetime
as
BEGIN
    select
        count(f.Id) as [Total],
        f.AccountCode,
        f.AccountName,
        f.Utc,
        f2.CityCode,
        f2.CityName
    from
        InnerPortal.Feedback.QueueFeedback f
    left join
        InnerPortal.Feedback.QueueFeedback f2
    on
        f2.AccountCode = f.AccountCode
    where
        (f.Done is null or f.Done = 0) and 
        (f.Busy is NULL or f.Busy = 0) and
        ((DATEPART(hour, DATEADD(HOUR, f.Utc, @dtNow)) >= 9 ) and
        (DATEPART(hour, DATEADD(HOUR, f.Utc, @dtNow)) <= 20))
    group by
        f.AccountCode, f2.CityCode,
        f2.CityName, f.AccountName, f.Utc
END
```

I group rows by `AccountName` and by `CityName`. As result we have something like a tree. The problem is the `[Total]` not calculates correctly. 
Then I get a select for a special AccountCode the count if much less then get me as result the procedure. For example:

```
select count(f.Id) from Feedback.QueueFeedback f where f.AccountCode = '01507'
```

returns 16 rows but the procedure result is 256.

The target is to get a count of collected rows with the same account. How to make it work correctly?
Thanks.

Software: T-Sql, Ms Sql server 2012

Comment: If you join the table with itself and it has 16 Rows with AccountCode 01507 this will be multiplied to 256. I am sure you are missing some Parent-Child relation to make a tree out of this Query. Someone might be able help you if you post some sample data and your expected output.

Comment: you're joining the table to itself on `AccountCode` which I assume is repeated multiple times, so you are getting rows duplicated , which will increase the count and explain why you get 256 rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure you want

```
count(distinct(f.Id))
```